# Letting a custom view grow with a MultiLineLabel subview

Tags: macos, autolayout, nstextfield

I have a simple custom view and within a Wrapping Label (Multi Line Label) as a subview. I used autolayout to set the constraints.

[image: Setup in interface builder]

Now I want that the superview change its size to show all content of the wrapping label. How can I achieve that? The wrapping laben shows the content of the extra text field (Outlet: "textfeld").

[image: Running]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the content hugging & compression resistance constraints on your label (among other constraints).

With the label selected, select the size inspector.  At the bottom, you'll see the Constraints section:

[image]

These have default values of around 250 & 750.  We need to boost these up to 1000.  These constraints control the way that the label grows & shrinks relative to its content, but with such low priority, every other autolayout constraint you add will take priority.  So we need to increase the priority of these constraints up to 1000 which marks them as required (or at a minimum, you need to increase the content compression resistance priorities).

Now you just implement other autolayout constraints around that which make sense.  For example, if you always want it to have at least a 20 pixel border from each side, be 20 pixels from the top, and centered in your superview, you might set up constraints like this:

[image]

Of course, with these constraints, if the parent view isn't constrained to a max width, you won't have implicitly forced any word wrapping, so it might expand the parent view's width.  We can add a max width constraint to our label too.

[image]

Comment: Thx for your answer, but it somehow doesn't work. I set up everything you said, but my label stays a one liner when I change my text at runtime. Can I send you my Xcode Project file somehow so you can check it?

Comment: It stays on one line, but does the label expand in width to fit the content?  If so, you have nothing to constraint the width and force wrapping.

Comment: Yes I have a fixed width constraint. You can even see at my first screenshot (at the bottom of the multi line view). When I add more text in Interface builder it works, but when I change the amount of text at runtime.

Comment: Upload your project to github and I will take a look.

Comment: just found a solution after watching some WWDC videos from 2012. In "applicationDidFinishLaunching" I set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth property of the multi line label to its width. Voilá, now the superview resizes by changing the text at runtime.